# Static caches in web services

Tags: web-services, caching

Is this the right way to initialize a static cache object in a web service?

```
public class someclass{
 private static Cache cache;
 static someclass()
    {
        cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
    }
}
```

More Info:

```
Seems like I receive more then one cache object from webservice. It creates a new request that only lasts for the duration of that call. If I move to a different machine, it creates a new request (and I think a webservice ) object that returns new cache. (because I can see two different caches being returned in the sniffer) By forcing it to be static I was hoping to have only one. However no avail. doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks good to me - especially if you are going to wrap the `Current.Context` and expose properties for cache values like this:

```
public static class CacheManager
{
    public static Boolean Foo
    {
        get { return (Boolean)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Foo"] }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Cache["Foo"] = value; }
    }

    // etc...
}
```

You don't really need to create a private reference to the current cache unless you are only doing so to save on typing.  Also notice that I made the class `static` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just access it directly using `HTTPContext.Current.Cache`?

Comment: Seems like I receive more then one cache object from webservice.
it creates a new request that only lasts for the duration of that call. If I move to a different machine, it creates a new request (and I think a webservice ) object that returns new cache. By forcing it to be static I was hoping to have only one. However no avail.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your machine. Are you specifying timeout values for the items in cache? Does your machine have only a small amount of RAM?